# MOLH Localizer helper for language switch in ios13 does not work as it's documentation guide

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios13, xcode11

I decide to implement my first iOS app which support more that one language, in the begging I'm success in make the language switch as the language system for the iPhone but I want the user switch the language from inside the app, after quick search I found this third party library which do exactly what I need **MOLH** the main thing this library do is reset the init viewController, it's work well with ios12 and Xcode 10 but when

```
open class func reset(transition: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate {
            if delegate is MOLHResetable {
                (delegate as!MOLHResetable).reset()
            }
            UIView.transition(with: ((delegate.window)!)!, duration: 0.5, options: transition, animations: {}) { (f) in
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I face an error here when unwrap default.window

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      if let delegate = SceneDelegate.shared?.window {
          if delegate is MOLHResetable {
                (delegate as! MOLHResetable).reset()
          } else{
          print("Not is MOLHResetable")

    }

        UIView.transition(with: SceneDelegate.shared!.window!, duration: 0.5, options: transition, animations: {}) { (f) in
       }


    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and write some text why and how your answer works please.